# Adding/removing duplicate options from dynamically generated dropdowns with the same class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a demo which can be found at http://beta.acinonyxsim.com/demo. When adding base or spot markings, you are allowed to add as many as you'd like. It is my intent and wish to disable the selected marking in all generated dropdowns but the one currently being manipulated. At this time, the code works in part, but doesn't seem fully to eliminate the possibility of having more than one of the same marking. In theory, the code should disable the marking in question in all other dropdowns and return it to enabled once it has been deselcted. My code is below (I apologize for any formatting errors, I am a blind programmer):

```
$('div#base_markings').on('change', 'select.base_marking', function(){
    var base_marking = $(this).val();
    $('select.base_marking').not(this).find('option[value="'+base_marking+'"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).find('option[value="'+base_marking+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    processDemo();
    showColors();
   });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: The demo now works as expected, only I can't seem to get the demo to reenable options removed dynamically by clicking 'Remove Base Marking' (or 'Remove Spot Marking'). Below is my code for the remove button for base markings:

```
   $('div#base_markings').on('click', 'button.remove_base_marking', function(){
    $('select.base_marking').each(function(){
        $('select.base_marking option[value="'+$(this).data('index')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).data('index', this.value);
        $('select.base_marking option[value="'+this.value+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $(this).closest('div.base_markings_options').remove();
    processDemo();
    base_marking_count --;
   });
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem seems to occur when clicking "Add a Base Marking", because the newly generated `<select>` will have all `option`s enabled even if there are some selected in another dropdown, right? You might need to append a loop to your `button#add_base_marking` click event that checks all existing `base_markings` selects to find their current values and disable them on the new select.

Comment: I hadn't looked at it quite that way, but you make a valid point. Are you willing to give an example of what you mean by containing it in a for loop? I've never quite seen that done with a jQuery .on event.

Comment: Oh, I just mean a loop like `'$('select.base_marking').each()`.

Comment: I'm still new enough to jQuery to have to ask where exactly that would go in the scheme of my own code. I can edit the question and add the full extent of the base markings section if needed.

Comment: Thanks to you, I am on the right track now. However, I'm having trouble when I remove the dynamically generated elements; I want the formerly unselected option in the removed element to reappear in all other dropdowns. My updated code and question are above.

Comment: Glad to see how far you made it! I left an answer below. Let me know if you have any more questions. If it helped, you can finally mark this question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is to your latest problem and follows the comments in the discussion above. This code should reenable the `option` in each `select` menu that belonged to the value that was just deleted.

```
$('div#base_markings').on('click', 'button.remove_base_marking', function() {

  // get value of the select menu that's being deleted
  var delValue = $(this).closest('.base_markings_options').find('select').val();

  // loop through each select
  $('select.base_marking').each(function() {

    // find the option with the deleted value and remove disabled attr
    $(this).find('option[value="' + delValue + '"]').removeProp('disabled');
  });

  $(this).closest('div.base_markings_options').remove();
  processDemo();
  base_marking_count--;
});
```